# Event binding issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="children">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And if we bind both parent and children with same events like :

```
     $("#parent").live({ mouseenter : Infocus , mouseleave : Outfocus });
     $("#children").live({ mouseenter : Infocus , mouseleave : Outfocus });
```

Now my problem is when i get my mouse over to the children the parent is also highlighted, Can anybody tell me whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use `stopPropagation()` for prevent event follow.

```
function Infocus(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // your code
}

function Outfocus(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // your code
}
```

Read about **[.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)**

You can do something like this: (may be not satisfactory)

```
$("#parent").live({
    mouseenter: Infocus,
    mouseleave: Outfocus
});
$("#children").live({
    mouseenter: Infocus,
    mouseleave: Outfocus
});

function Infocus(e) {
    if(this.id == 'parent') {
        $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
    } else if(this.id == 'children') {
        $(this).css('background', 'green');
        $(this).parent().trigger('mouseleave')
    }
}

function Outfocus(e) {
    if(this.id == 'parent') {
        $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
    } else if(this.id == 'children') {
        $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
        $(this).parent().trigger('mouseenter')
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uMbfL/6/)**

Answer (score 2):

Even if the other answer is accurate in a sense. I think your problem is another one.
What I think you are doing is highlighting on `mouseenter` and removing the highlighting on `mouseleave` but what is actually happening is different.

You never leave `#parent` when moving over `#children`. In a image if you move your mouse from left `(1)` to right `(5)` these are the triggered events:

```
                +-----------------------------------+
                |#parent                            |
                |                                   |
                |                                   |
                |          +-------------+          |
                |          |#children    |          |
                |          |             |          |
          (1)   |    (2)   |     (3)     |   (4)    |   (5)
                |          |             |          |
                |          |             |          |
                |          +-------------+          |
                |                                   |
                |                                   |
                |                                   |
                +-----------------------------------+
```

1. nothing.
2. `#parent.mouseenter`
3. `#children.mouseenter`
4. `#children.mouseleave`
5. `#parent.mouseleave`

If this is the case then you need to modify your highlighting logic.